# why does Magento prevent display of root category

Tags: magento, categories, layered-navigation

Magento's `categoryController::viewAction()` calls the category Helper which explicitly denies the display of the root category.

```
public function canShow($category){
...
if (!$category->isInRootCategoryList()) {
        return false;
}
```

Other than performance, are there specific reasons why this category would be prevented from display?

Our client would like to display all products on one page with layered navigation filters, and using the Root Category with `isAnchor = true` would be ideal.

Comment: By the way, the snippet here suggests that when the category is NOT root it should not be shown. I'm not getting it.